# does http transfer files over FTP?

Tags: http, ftp

I've read something that looks wired to me!
I was reading an article  that said HTTP uses FTP to transfer files!
I want to know is it true? if yes, how it transfers? 
I mean how it can distinguish if it's a file and it's transferable over FTP? for example I can read a file with **PHP** and send it to user or just create a link to file! in both, headers can be same but in first case, it's impossible to transfer it over FTP!!!

**Edit:** I really appreciate if you provide me  a good resource on this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah HTTP and FTP both run on the TCP protocol and do not piggy back on one another.

Comment: It is possible to tunnel FTP connections through some HTTP proxies, though.

Comment: Technically it's possible to use almost any transmission protocol as a proxy. Data is data. It's just not typically done.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP doesn't use FTP to transfer files. HTTP is a protocol in it's own right (HyperText Transfer Protocol) rather than FTP (File Transfer Protocol) but both use TCP transport layer.

Answer (score 2):

the protocol hierarchy is

```
{http,ftp,xxx} -> {tcp,udp} -> ip
```

`http` and `ftp` are on the same layer(application layer)
have a look at [Internet_protocol_suite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite)

Answer (score 1):

No HTTP don't use FTP for file transfer, but some HTTP client libraries like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) can handle both HTTP & FTP, and of course a web page can have `ftp://some.org/some/ftp.link` links

FTP is perhaps slightly faster, but is more complex and uses 2 connections (one for data, one for control).

There are many resources (and even books) on [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) and [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol). I found good [Shiflett's HTTP Developer's Handbook](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0672324547) but there are many many others. Go to a library to find them.

Comment: I don't know, it is more a rumor and some old experimental feeling. (this is why I said "perhaps slightly").